# unfortunately.the program has stopped in android

Tags: android, runtime-error

I have already looked all of the questions.i wrote my codes and it has no errors but still i get the same message. what can i do just show me a way i will fix it by myself

```
public class RunningSum extends Activity {


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_running_sum);
    Button sum = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button cancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    EditText from = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    EditText upto = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    final EditText rsum = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    final int from1 = Integer.valueOf(from.getText().toString());
    final int upto1 = Integer.valueOf(upto.getText().toString());
    final int rsum1 = Integer.valueOf(rsum.getText().toString());
    cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub



        }
    });


    sum.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public  void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            for(int x=from1; from1<=upto1; x++){
                int summ = 0;
                summ += from1;
                rsum.setText(summ);
            }


            }



    });

}




@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_running_sum, menu);
    return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the messages in the logcat?

Comment: there are a lot of exceptions in the logcat

Comment: When you run your code look at the last messages/exceptions and work from there on backwards.

Comment: i think that is the logical way the fix it.thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Your loop is probably an infinite loop. Your condition `from1<=upto1` never changes.

Comment: to add to this, since from1 never changes, the loop will never end and the app will go into [ANR](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/responsiveness.html)

Comment: Yeah I think you are looking for the condition x<=upto1 instead from1<=upto1.  Change that and you may be good to go.

Comment: but when i delete the for loop it still does not work.i mean when is delete the converrting methods,then the program shows something

Comment: Post the logcat info for further comments.

Answer (score -1):

Probably `rsum.setText(summ);` is the culprit. [setText(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText%28int%29) expects a resource id, not an arbitrary integer. If you want to show the sum, you must convert it to a `CharSequence` first and set this.

You can also rewrite your for loop to `summ = from1 * (upto1 - from1 + 1);`, which should be a lot cheaper and set the `EditText` afterwards.

Comment: It doesn't give a compile error, because you give it an integer. But you will get a runtime error, when there's no such resource. Look into the logcat or post it here.